# javascript regex to php regex UTF-8 chars email verification

Tags: php, javascript, regex, email, email-verification

OK, so I have this big regex to check emails in **javascript** :

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i
```

I want to use this in **php with preg_match**

But I get this error:

> Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u
>   at offset 44 in
>   some.php

So the problems are that ***\u*** chars so how to convert this regex to PHP so I can check emails even if browser is with disabled javascript. So that ***\u00A0*** are some UTF-8 chars I saw somewhere that I have to escape the backslash but even with all escaped backslashes the error is still the same so please help me convert this regex

Comment: *sigh* please [don't validate email addresses](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) with such complex regexes. Just use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a PCRE expression that *truly and reliably* checks for valid emails, this is the only expression I know of that works, more or less. [found it here](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html):

> (?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
>   )+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
>   \r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
>   ?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
>   \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\0
>   31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*\
>   ](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+
>   (?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:
>   (?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
>   |(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
>   ?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
>   r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[
>    \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
>   ?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
>   )*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
>    \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
>   )(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
>   )+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
>   *:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
>   |\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
>   \n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
>   \r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
>   ]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031
>   ]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](
>   ?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?
>   :(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?
>   :\r\n)?[ \t])*))*>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?
>   :(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
>   [ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] 
>   \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|
>   \.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
>   @,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"
>   (?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
>   )*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\
>   ".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
>   :[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[
>   ]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-
>   \031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(
>   ?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
>   :\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([
>   ^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\"
>   .[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[\
>   ]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".\
>   [] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\
>   r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] 
>   \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]
>   |\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \0
>   00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\
>   .|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
>   ;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?
>   :[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
>   (?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".
>   []]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
>   ^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]
>   ]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
>   ?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\
>   ".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(
>   ?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
>   ["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
>   ])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
>   ])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
>   :.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
>   \Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
>   [^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[\
>   ]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
>   ?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["
>   ()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)
>   ?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>
>   @,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
>    \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,
>   ;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
>   )*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\
>   ".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
>   (?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".
>   []]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:.(?:(?:
>   \r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[[
>   "()<>@,;:\".[]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\]|\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
>   *))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
>   +|\Z|(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
>   .(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\".[] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
>   |(?=[["()<>@,;:\".[]]))|[([^[]\r\]|\.)*](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*>(?:(
>   ?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)

If however, you want to be sane:

```
if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
}
```

Is probably a more readable, and just generally better bet :)